# Magento - how to locate the location of inline css

Tags: css, magento, inline

I want to locate the location of the css inline item so that I can edit the background color of a horizontal menu.

This is what the css looks like:

```
ul#megamenupro_1 li.menu-item-link a { background: none repeat scroll 0% 
0% #5EA032 !important; )
```

The firefox inspector is telling me that it's an inline item.

I want to change the `#5EA032` colored background to another color. The thing is, it's an inline css so I don't know where to find it in magento. I tried looking in `page.xml`, `header.phtml`, `theme.css`, and `style.css` but it doesn't seem to be in any of these.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to locate inline css items in magento, or where it could possibly be located? I would like to change the background color.

Thank you!

Comment: if it's inline css it'll be in the actual html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to

```
System >> Configurations >> Developer
```

then select the required `store view` from `Current Configuration Scope` from top left drop-down. Then under `Debug` tab, enable the `Template Paht hints` and save. Once done, refresh your frontend page, you will see paths to all files shown in red. Use firebug in Firefox browser to locate the inline css and get the file name and path.